# warning： mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50537 Library:50623

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

warning： mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50537 Library:50623

How do I do with it? I think I have a different version between mysql client and server, but after I updated by using yum, this wranning appear again.
System：centos

Comment: did you also update php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version mismatch.  I tried removing php-mysql and replace it with php-mysqlnd to in order to fix the conflict.

On Centos, running the one liner

`rpm -e --nodeps php-mysql && yum install php-mysqlnd -y && service httpd graceful`

according to the answer at the bottom of this [page](https://atomicorp.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7667) got the  `php-mysqlnd` installed.

But be warned, this **`rpm --nodeps`** option is considered harmful according to http://www.tummy.com/blogs/2005/08/12/-force-nodeps-considered-harmful/.

My server doesn't show the errors after doing that.

I'm using Centos 7, php-mysqlnd-5.4.16-23,  php 5.4.16, mysql Distrib 5.6.23, and apache 2.2.x